# cast boolean into string to fetch core data

Tags: swift, casting, boolean, fetch

In my swift code I am attempting to fetch boolean values from a core data boolean attribute. I am getting a error at if let imageData = trueString stating Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'. I tried to cast my value in the line above but its not working.

```
func getBool(imageNo:Int) {
   // first check the array bounds
   let info = helpBool.shareInstance.fetchBool()
    
    print("image count is", info.count)
   if info.count > imageNo {
       
       // check if the data is available
       
       
       let trueString = String(info[imageNo].bool)
       
       if let imageData = trueString
        {
      print(imageData)
           
       } else {
           // no data
           print("data is empty Textss")
       }
   } else {
       // image number is greater than array bounds
       print("you are asking out of bounds")
   }
}
```

Comment: `trueString` is not optional, so you can't use `if let`. Simply use `trueString` as it is. But I assume you'll want to check the string is not blank, like `if trueString != "" { }`

Comment: how would i check if imageData = trueString if I cant use if let.

Comment: your `imageData` object doesn't exist. The `if let imageData = trueString` is trying to create it. But because `trueString` is not Optional, you can't create it using `if let`